# Is there a way to force one List Item per column using multi-column layout?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have some simple HTML and CSS to split a list into 4 columns. Instead of the normal behavior where it fits each list item into whichever column has enough space for it, I want to force it to put each list item into its own column.

So in my example `<li>Column 1</li>` will always only be in the 1st column. `<li>Column 2<br>Column 2<br>Column 2<br>Column 2</li>` will always only be in the 2nd column. Same with column 3 and 4.

Is there a way to accomplish this while using the `columns` property?

```css
ul.data-points {
  columns: 4;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="data-points">
  <li>Column 1</li>
  <li>Column 2<br>Column 2<br>Column 2<br>Column 2</li>
  <li>Column 3</li>
  <li>Column 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not simply use flexbox ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Because in order to have equal spacing between equal width columns in flexbox, you need to set x margins on the cells and then a negative margin on the flex container in order to remove the far left and far right margins while keeping the columns the same width. It feels hack-ish to me, so if list columns could be made to have 1 list item per column, it would be a much cleaner way to have equal width columns and equal width spacing between them.

Comment: If you want space in between you can use margins on the children just how you're using `column-gap: 20px;` it will give out the exact same layout only better, here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yhq8m52u/)

Comment: @ZohirSalak thanks for that example! I obviously don't know enough about flexbox, because that works great and it's nice and simple...

Answer (score 2):

This is more suitable for CSS grid:

```css
ul.data-points {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="data-points">
  <li>Column 1</li>
  <li>Column 2<br>Column 2<br>Column 2<br>Column 2</li>
  <li>Column 3</li>
  <li>Column 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

as answered a couple of hours ago. at [2 column lists gets separated by its heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796802/2-column-lists-gets-separated-by-its-heading/60797686#60797686)

**set li to inline-block to avoid it to spray through columns** and a bottom padding or margin to hopefully push next one to next column .

## **However, it looks like a typical grid or flex layout, not CSS Column** .

### demo below demonstrates how not efficient css column is here.

```css
ul.data-points {
  columns: 4;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
li {display:inline-block;width:100%;margin-bottom:100%;}
```

```html
<ul class="data-points">
  <li>Column 1</li>
  <li>Column 2<br>Column 2<br>Column 2<br>Column 2</li>
  <li>Column 3</li>
  <li>Column 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it works without inline-block on my side. With inline-block It's scrambled (testing on Chrome)

Comment: @TemaniAfif margin-bottom makes it work on itsel in ff, inline-block is to avoid to break li through columns . the css break rules never work inside column ;) ... chrome doesn't handle the margin trick :( however it is a flex or grid job ;)

Comment: removing inline-block make it works in all the browser when testing (not sure about different OS, testing on Windows)

Comment: This is only displaying as a 2 column layout

Comment: @Gavin , because you run Chrome, this answer is to demonstrate that column CSS is not the option to use, this is a grid or flex layout , **not CSS column** take care.